# Avoid session replication in Spring rest application using Cookies

Tags: java, session, cookies, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am working on `Spring 4 mvc` application with `mysql` database, `tomcat` server.
Basically, I am creating a Spring rest which will be used by `Angular JS`.

**Note:** I am not using `Spring security`

In order to avoid session replication in case of `clustered environment`, I am using `cookie` approach.On login, I am generating `one unique session id` (`using java UUID`) and use it to create a `cookie` and then set the cookie in the response.Also, storing that session id in database along with any user data.

In order to authenticate every rest API, I have written a `Spring interceptor` which will intercept every rest API call which in turn check if there is a cookie in the request.If it is present, I am fetching session id value and using it, making a database call to check if it is valid or not. On logout, I am deleting the cookie.

Base on what i am doing as explained above, I have few questions:

```
1) Is my approach correct? or do you see any flaw in it.  
2) Let me know if there is any other better method to achieve the same i.e. to avoid session replication.  
3) Since, I am not using any HTTP session, how do I achieve something like session-timeout or do i even need it?
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is my approach correct? or do you see any flaw in it.

Its a good approach. Just a couple of points though in order of precedence:-

- If you are using your API to service ***alot*** of requests then think about using in-memory cache rather then DB. Going to DB is relatively much more expensive. ***Alot*** is subjective I know and it depends on your setup, but just consider the DB for data you want to live beyond sessions. Better to use a more temporary/faster store such as an in-memory cache for things like API tokens. If across a cluster then explore a distributed cache solution.
- Using cookies is not necessarily a security risk but have a bit of a read about [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). More secure to pass the token in a HTTP Header rather than in the cookie itself - that is if you are concerned about CSRF (I do use the Header approach in my own apps but I think CSRF is relatively rare and it depends on how sensitive your data is)

> 2) Let me know if there is any other better method to achieve the same
>   i.e. to avoid session replication.

Nothing to add over response to 1.)

> 3) Since, I am not using any HTTP session, how do I achieve something like session-timeout or do i even need it?

Store (preferably in cache) a timestamp with the token, and refresh it in the cache for each transaction that uses the token. Then, when checking if you consider if the token is valid, check the timestamp and you can decide (based on time elapsed) if you wish to remove the token and request the client to re-authenticate.